# Can I use number helper on jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use [number_with_delimiter](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_delimiter) method when onchange on input field is active. Is it possible to do that?

The requirement is whenever user type on number field, the field should show the number as thousand separator.

Comment: You can use `toLocaleString()` funciton , for an example, `var n = 34523453.345` `n.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, but highly unpractical since you would need to send a Ajax request to the server for it to return a formatted number. Formatting the number in JS is a far better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use below global function

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```